# What joins does SQLite support?

Tags: sqlite, join

According to [the join-op syntax](http://sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#join-op), SQLite has 13 distinct join statements:

```
,
JOIN
LEFT JOIN
OUTER JOIN
LEFT OUTER JOIN
INNER JOIN
CROSS JOIN
NATURAL JOIN
NATURAL LEFT JOIN
NATURAL OUTER JOIN
NATURAL LEFT OUTER JOIN
NATURAL INNER JOIN
NATURAL CROSS JOIN
```

Are they all unique? Which are equivalent?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The SQLite grammar is a bit different from [the SQL-92 spec](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt)'s, according to which, the following are illegal:

```
*OUTER JOIN
*NATURAL OUTER JOIN
*NATURAL CROSS JOIN
```

The first two, because a `<join type>`, in order to contain `OUTER`, must also include an `<outer join type>` before it. The last, because `NATURAL` can only occur in `<qualified join>`'s, not `<cross join>`'s. These don't appear to behave according to any spec, so it's a good idea to avoid them.

As was answered on [the mailing list](http://sqlite.org:8080/cgi-bin/mailman/private/sqlite-users/2009-April/011007.html), SQLite3 only supports three joins: `CROSS JOIN`, `INNER JOIN`, and `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. The following are equivalent:

```
, == CROSS JOIN
JOIN == INNER JOIN
LEFT JOIN == LEFT OUTER JOIN
```

As explained in [the wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Natural_join) the NATURAL keyword is shorthand for finding and matching on same-name columns, and doesn't affect the the join type.

According to the [SQLite page](http://sqlite.org/omitted.html), '`RIGHT`' and '`FULL`'  `OUTER JOIN`'s are not supported.

Comment: No RIGHT OUTER or FULL OUTER support?

Comment: As of June 26, 2022, SQLite now supports RIGHT and FULL OUTER JOIN in [v3.39.0](https://sqlite.org/releaselog/3_39_0.html)

Answer (score 1):

An update: In addition to the above JOIN statements, SQLite now supports RIGHT and FULL OUTER JOIN as of 3.39.0 released today (June 26th, 2022): https://sqlite.org/releaselog/3_39_0.html

Comment: This is not really an answer to the original question, but would fit as a comment to an answer.

Comment: I need 50 reputation to comment.