# in appcelerator titanium sql left join is not working

Tags: sql, database, titanium, appcelerator

i'm working on APPCELERATOR TITANIUM.

i'm using a database in which strangely some sql queries are not working properly like this for instance:

```
db.execute("SELECT Location_Diners.Dining_Time,Location_Diners.First_Name,Location_Diners.Last_Name,Location_Diners.PartySize,Location_Diners.Diner_ID,Location_Diners.DinerStatusColor_ID,Location_Diners.Notes,Location_Diners.Diner_ID,Location_SeatedDiners.Table_ID FROM Location_Diners LEFT JOIN Location_SeatedDiners ON Location_Diners.Diner_ID=Location_SeatedDiners.Diner_ID");
```

this is the error i'm getting please help me out here.....

```
2011-12-21 11:47:29.416 abc[5254:ac03] [ERROR] A SQLite database error occurred on database '/Users/../iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/C377123C-7A2A-4FDF-9314-428713C885FD/Library/Application Support/database.sql': Error Domain=com.plausiblelabs.pldatabase Code=3 "An error occured parsing the provided SQL statement." UserInfo=0x6ad4330 {com.plausiblelabs.pldatabase.error.vendor.code=1, NSLocalizedDescription=An error occured parsing the provided SQL statement., com.plausiblelabs.pldatabase.error.query.string=SELECT Location_Diners.Dining_Time,Location_Diners.First_Name,Location_Diners.Last_Name,Location_Diners.PartySize,Location_Diners.Diner_ID,Location_Diners.DinerStatusColor_ID,Location_Diners.Notes,Location_Diners.Diner_ID,Location_SeatedDiners.Table_ID FROM Location_Diners LEFT JOIN Location_SeatedDiners ON Location_Diners.Diner_ID=Location_SeatedDiners.Diner_ID, com.plausiblelabs.pldatabase.error.vendor.string=no such table: Location_Diners} (SQLite #1: no such table: Location_Diners) (query: 'SELECT Location_Diners.Dining_Time,Location_Diners.First_Name,Location_Diners.Last_Name,Location_Diners.PartySize,Location_Diners.Diner_ID,Location_Diners.DinerStatusColor_ID,Location_Diners.Notes,Location_Diners.Diner_ID,Location_SeatedDiners.Table_ID FROM Location_Diners LEFT JOIN Location_SeatedDiners ON Location_Diners.Diner_ID=Location_SeatedDiners.Diner_ID')
[ERROR] invalid SQL statement. Error Domain=com.plausiblelabs.pldatabase Code=3 "An error occured parsing the provided SQL statement." UserInfo=0x6ad4330 {com.plausiblelabs.pldatabase.error.vendor.code=1, NSLocalizedDescription=An error occured parsing the provided SQL statement., com.plausiblelabs.pldatabase.error.query.string=SELECT Location_Diners.Dining_Time,Location_Diners.First_Name,Location_Diners.Last_Name,Location_Diners.PartySize,Location_Diners.Diner_ID,Location_Diners.DinerStatusColor_ID,Location_Diners.Notes,Location_Diners.Diner_ID,Location_SeatedDiners.Table_ID FROM Location_Diners LEFT JOIN Location_SeatedDiners ON Location_Diners.Diner_ID=Location_SeatedDiners.Diner_ID, com.plausiblelabs.pldatabase.error.vendor.string=no such table: Location_Diners} in -[TiDatabaseProxy execute:] (TiDatabaseProxy.m:136)
```

any help is highly appreciated ................

Comment: confirm that both table exits

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hey Prateek I think you should use LEFT OUTER JOIN.
Check this,

[What joins does SQLite support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774475/what-joins-does-sqlite-support)

According to this LEFT JOIN = LEFT OUTER JOIN but the keyword LEFT OUTER JOIN in supported in SQLite3.

Answer (score 0):

As seen [here](http://www.shokhirev.com/nikolai/abc/sql/joins.html) you need to do `LEFT OUTER JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT Location_Diners.Dining_Time,
  Location_Diners.First_Name,
  Location_Diners.Last_Name,
  Location_Diners.PartySize,
  Location_Diners.Diner_ID,
  Location_Diners.DinerStatusColor_ID,
  Location_Diners.Notes,
  Location_Diners.Diner_ID,
  Location_SeatedDiners.Table_ID
FROM Location_Diners
LEFT OUTER JOIN Location_SeatedDiners ON Location_Diners.Diner_ID=Location_SeatedDiners.Diner_ID
```