# joining two tables in android sqlite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

how to join in android database sqlite

Comment: sqlite does not support full outer joins and right joins ..

Comment: `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: RIGHT and FULL OUTER JOINs are not currently supported` this more clearly tells you,what is it thats not understandable ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [What joins does SQLite support?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774475/what-joins-does-sqlite-support)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used queries to URL conversions.

OData v4 introduces a new operators, which may resolve your scenario.

For more please reference this:http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/odata-v4.0-part2-url-conventions.html,

Answer (score 0):

this is how I usually select and join between two or more different tables :

```
SELECT master_spaj._id,master_spaj.SPAJ_ID,pemegang_polis.nama_pp,table_tertanggung.nama_tt,master_spaj.IdProposal FROM master_spaj,pemegang_polis,table_tertanggung WHERE master_spaj.SPAJ_ID=pemegang_polis.SPAJ_ID AND master_spaj.SPAJ_ID=table_tertanggung.SPAJ_ID
```

Comment: can u find problem in my query? why i am getting that exception

Comment: have u try to implement my example code?

Comment: but i need to join table to get data

Comment: sure, with this code, you can get data from multiple table.